# c# classes Subscribing to events of each other

Tags: c#, events, c#-4.0

Class A has an event. Class B wants to subscribe to it. Class B has an event and class A wants to subscribe to it.

I tried by creating object of class B in A and class A in B. But it's a deadlock.

I need help here...

[image: Please check this image]

Grey rectangles must be events. Arrow indicates that an event has to be raised from class to class

```
class A
{
B b;
public event EventHandler eventA;

OnEventA()
{
eventA();
}

public A()
{
b= new B();
b.eventB += DoSomethingElse();
}

}


class B
{
A a;
public B()
{
    a= new A();
    a.eventA += DoSomething();
}
public event EventHandler eventB;

OnEventB()
{
eventB();
}


}
```

Comment: The fact that you are trying this indicates there is a problem in the design. Please provide a little more context on the problem so we can help you out!

Comment: I edited the question. Can you help me?

Comment: Why do you think there is a deadlock? This should not cause a deadlock.

Comment: I updated again with the code I tried.

Comment: Perfectly valid question with code and diagram. 2 downvotes and a close vote. What's happening to this site...

Comment: @CodingYoshi The first revision of OP's post doesn't include any code or diagram, hence explains why it has 2 DVs & a close vote.

Comment: @anu - Real code would be good. Your code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code you need:

```
class A
{
    B b;
    public event EventHandler eventA;

    void OnEventA()
    {
        var ea = this.eventA;
        if (ea != null)
        {
            ea(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public A()
    {
        this.b = new B(this);
        this.b.eventB += DoSomethingElse;
    }

    private void DoSomethingElse(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}

class B
{
    A a;
    public B(A a)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.a.eventA += DoSomething;
    }
    public event EventHandler eventB;

    void OnEventB()
    {
        var eb = this.eventB;
        if (eb != null)
        {
            eb(this, new EventArgs());
        }       
    }

    private void DoSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }   
}
```

Comment: You saved my day. I totally forgot the concept of Parameterized Constructors. Thanks a ton. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your issue is that you don't get the right instances to talk to each other, here's one approach that might help you:

In you constructor for type `A`, create the instance of type `B` and set the reference to your current instance of `A` (`this`).

```
public A()
{
    // give B reference to A
    b = new B(this);
    // subscribe A to B's event
    b.eventB += DoSomethingElse();
}
```

In order for this to work you'll need to have the constructor of type `B` accept a reference to an `A` like this:

```
public B(A a)
{
    // subscribe B to A's event
    a.eventA += DoSomething();
}
```

You may also want to read up on unsubscribing from the events in order to make sure that you release resources properly. Check these links:

[What best practices for cleaning up event handler references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258064/what-best-practices-for-cleaning-up-event-handler-references)

[Should I always disconnect event handlers in the Dispose method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399991/should-i-always-disconnect-event-handlers-in-the-dispose-method)